# SQL Server codeonly connection timeout

Tags: .net, sql-server, timeout

I just installed SQL Server 2012 alongside SQL Server 2008 R2

I can connect to it locally no problem

But when I try to connect via another pc on my LAN, I get a timeout:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.

Here's the code

```
Dim queryString = "SELECT * FROM cities"
Using connection As New SqlConnection("data source=PCBOX\MSSERVER;initial catalog=MYDB;persist security info=True;user id=ABC;password=123;Connection Timeout=30")
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
    connection.Open()
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}", reader(0), reader(1)))
    End While
End Using
Dim a = New MYDBEntities
Dim b = a.Cities.ToList
```

now a few interesting notes:

1. I could connect from ssms even from the LAN
2. when I connect from ssms via LAN, I always first get a timeout in ssms, and only on the second try does it connect instantly.
3. the exception is thrown only when I'm querying via code. the same exception is via sqlconnection or EF
4. visual studio itself has no trouble connection to the DB, as it shows the EF wizard and shows the available tables, creates classes etc...
5. the query I can execute in a split second from ssms on the LAN, I get back 4 rows (that's all) in a jiffy

What can the problem be?

I tried:

1. enabling any client protocols I can in the configuration manager
2. restarting any services I thought relevant (agent, browser...)
3. restarted the whole server pc
4. changing the password
5. looking in SQL Server logs (does not seem to show any attempted connection, though I might be looking in the wrong place)
6. looking in windows firewall log (C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log) it's empty
7. installing SQL Server 2012 on client machine
8. setting the port in the connection string to 1433 (both versions are set to 1433 by me, is that ok?). but then i get another error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>   
>   What else can be done?

Comment: Maybe try select getdate() to see if has to do with that table.

Comment: same error. also the code crashes on the `connection.open` line. so i don't thing it has any connection to the sql statement itself.

Comment: You have two SQL server listening on the same port ?????

Comment: yes. i understand thats a problem? i just changed the tcp port (in client protocols properties) to 1434 (instead of 1433) i still get the same `network-related or instance-specific...` err in .net. in ssms its still hit and miss. some times i could connect sometimes not.

Comment: Shut down the other SQL completely and set everything to 1433.  Drop the userID from the DB.  Delete and recreate the userID.  Add the userID to the db.  Reboot both client and server.

Comment: thank you for your time. in services.msc i stopped sql server and agent for the 2008r2 instance. i also set them to manual. then i set the tcpip protocol to 1433 for 32&64 bit client protocols from mssql 11. then i dropped the login from the 2012 server and made a new login. i rebooted both pcs. on the client in ssms, i still have the same exact issue (first timeout then login) the only change is that now in the application its working like ssms. first run is a timeout, second run logs in. whats next?

Comment: I is a reach but try connecting by IP address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this link that looks a lot like your issue. Click [here](https://serverfault.com/a/195713)  You may want try opening the ports on the firewall, in case the firewall is not logging dropped connections.

Answer (score 2):

Since you installed SQL Server 2012 alongside SQL Server 2008 R2 I would try connecting without using the default port.

To find the port that SQL Server 2012 is using, go to SQL "SQL Server Configuration Manager in the Client 11 Protocols section. Look at the properties of ports on the TCP/IP protocol.

In your code after the instance name add a comma than the port number.

```
data source=PCBOX\MSSERVER,1434;
```

This it could be something besides the port.

Comment: hi thanks. i tried with the port in the connectionstring. but that gave a different error. i just added it to the original post. please see number 8. thanks

Comment: I found this link that looks a lot like your issue.  http://serverfault.com/a/195713 You may want try opening the ports on the firewall, in case the firewall is not logging dropped connections.

Comment: yup! that's it. doing the setting in IPALL and running the firewall scripts in that answer, fixed the problem in a jiffy. please make this an "answer" so i can "accept" it.thanks a billion!